# z3python: converting string to expression

Tags: python, z3

Given that `x,y,z = Ints('x y z')`  and a string like `s='x + y + 2*z = 5'`,  is there a quick way to convert s into a z3 expression ?   If it's not possible then it seems I have to do lots of string operations to do the conversion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the Python `eval` function. Here is an example:

```
from z3 import *
x,y,z = Ints('x y z') 
s = 'x + y + 2*z == 5'
F = eval(s)
solve(F)
```

This script displays `[y = 0, z = 0, x = 5]` on my machine.

Unfortunately, we can't execute this script at http://rise4fun.com/z3py. The rise4fun website rejects Python scripts containing `eval` (for security reasons).

Comment: Taking this one step further,  if I don't have `x,y,z` declared ahead of time -- how would I automatically declare `x,y,z` ?  assume I know all variables in `'x+y+2*z==5'`  are of type `Int`.

Comment: I was able to achieve variable declaration using `exec`, e.g., `exec("x,y,z = Ints('x y z')")`.  I am wondering if there's better way to do so.  `exec/eval` are dangerous operations in Python

Comment: Yes, `eval` is quite dangerous. The Z3 API only has parsers for SMT 2.0, SMT 1.0 and Z3 internal format. However, none of these formats are user friendly. For example, the SMT formats use s-expressions instead of the more natural infix notation. You can try one of the many parser generators available in Python. They will give you maximum flexibility. See this article: http://www.python.org/workshops/1998-11/proceedings/papers/aycock-little/aycock-little.ps