# Substitute SymPy Symbols with other types (Z3Py)

Tags: sympy, z3, z3py

I'm using SymPy expressions to compute expressions such as `a + 3 * b` that then I want to verify with Z3 (for example, `a + 3 * b > 0` for all positive `a, b`).

I can't find a way to replace `a, b` and in general SymPy symbols with Z3 objects.

```
import sympy
from z3 import *

a = sympy.Symbol('a')
b = sympy.Symbol('b')

t = Real('t')
w = Real('w')

e = a + 3 * b
e = e.subs({a:t, b:w})  # does nothing?
e = e.replace(a, t).replace(b, w)  # e = t + 3 * w

And(True, e > 0)  # raises z3.z3types.Z3Exception
```

The exception is thrown also by replacing `3` with `RealVal('3')`.

I'm currently operating on strings and finally using `exec` to change types and expressions as above, but I'm planning to stop using `exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix and match sympy expressions with z3py expressions. They are different internal data-structures. However, you can walk through the sympy expression and create a corresponding z3 expression, but it has to be done separately. Note that the call to `subs` is doing a substitution in the sympy world: The substitution is happening, but the resulting expression is still a sympy expression. (And most likely an illegal one: if you actually do try to use any sympy functions on it, you'll most likely get a similar exception from sympy itself.)

You need to develop a function that takes a sympy expression and gives you a z3py expression.

As far as I know there is no "official" function to do this, but see this (somewhat dated) answer for details: [How to use Z3py and Sympy together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488553/how-to-use-z3py-and-sympy-together) You might be able to use the code from there to serve your purposes. (A rough guess: Doing a full converter from sympy to z3py might very well be impossible due to the richness of sympy and the inevitable mismatches, but you can most likely get a converter that handles your use cases.)